# Perl non-greedy match

Tags: regex, perl, regex-greedy

I want only the first pattern up to slash_flash captured.

I tried this:

```
$var1 = slash_flash*_target_bit[*]_slash_hit\n

$var1 =~ s/^(.*)\*?(.*)$/$1/g if ($var1 =~ /\*/);
```

I get the entire string back:

```
> $var1 = slash_flash*_target_bit[*]_slash_hit
```

Note: $var1 can start with anything. So you can't start pattern matching with a particular word or pattern. That's why I tried (.*)

Answer (score 2):

First, post the code you actually ran. What you said isn't true because what you posted doesn't even compile.

Moving on.

- `\*?` can match zero characters.
- `.*` can match zero characters.

So once the first `.*` matches the whole string, `\*?` and `.*` happily match zero characters.

Maybe you want

```
$var =~ s/^([^*]*)\*.*$/$1/g if ($var1 =~ /\*/);
```

which can be shortened to

```
$var =~ s/^([^*]*)\*.*$/$1/;
```

Or even to

```
$var =~ s/^[^*]*\K\*.*$//;
```

Comment: I had an updated question based on this. How do I make the pattern match any of the following two lines :'code' $var1 = slash_flashold_target_bit[0] or $var1 = clone_flashnew_target_bit[5]

Comment: @cosmo kramer, Depends on specific you want to be `/.*/` would work. `/^(?:slash_flashold_target_bit\[0\]|clone_flashnew_target_bit\[5\])\z/` would match only those two lines. Maybe you're looking for something like `/_flashold_target_bit\[[0-9]+\]\z/`.